# Microphone doesn't work until volume is adjusted, regardless of actual volume

Tags: sound, microphone

I have an external microphone (Sennheiser SD Pro 2, which Ubuntu recognizes as "Sennheiser SD for Lync") and I've had this problem with Ubuntu 19.10 and 20.04 beta. After a (re)boot, my microphone is so quiet that it's practically muted (but not *actually* muted). When I look at the volume indicator in the gnome control panel, if I blow across the mic it just barely registers the noise. The volume control is set to about 95% by default.

If I then tweak the volume control 1-2% in either direction, the microphone behaves normally and the volume indicator spikes as expected when blowing into the mic. And yet, the volume setpoint has barely changed at all. It's just that *some* change is necessary to trigger the microphone to start working normally.

Here's the output from amixer before and after adjusting the volume, you can see that the absolute volume has barely changed but in reality it's practically muted before, and working normally after:

```
$ amixer -c 2
Simple mixer control 'Headset',0
  Capabilities: pvolume pvolume-joined cvolume cvolume-joined pswitch pswitch-joined
  Playback channels: Mono
  Capture channels: Mono
  Limits: Playback 0 - 100 Capture 0 - 100
  Mono: Playback 0 [0%] [-30.00dB] [on] Capture 93 [93%] [-2.10dB]
Simple mixer control 'Headset',1
  Capabilities: pvolume pvolume-joined
  Playback channels: Mono
  Limits: Playback 0 - 70
  Mono: Playback 51 [73%] [-5.70dB]

$ amixer -c 2
Simple mixer control 'Headset',0
  Capabilities: pvolume pvolume-joined cvolume cvolume-joined pswitch pswitch-joined
  Playback channels: Mono
  Capture channels: Mono
  Limits: Playback 0 - 100 Capture 0 - 100
  Mono: Playback 0 [0%] [-30.00dB] [on] Capture 91 [91%] [-2.70dB]
Simple mixer control 'Headset',1
  Capabilities: pvolume pvolume-joined
  Playback channels: Mono
  Limits: Playback 0 - 70
  Mono: Playback 51 [73%] [-5.70dB]
```

I've actually written a [startup script](https://github.com/danepowell/dotfiles/blob/master/set-headset-volume.sh) to automatically tweak the volume just enough to "fix" this, but that's obviously a hack and doesn't always work. Any ideas how I can troubleshoot this?

Answer (score 0):

Actually for the moment this seems to have been fixed by updating the headset firmware (I didn't know there was such a thing!). If the issue continues to occur I'll update here.